# Freopen Refuses to Append to File Just Overwrites

Tags: c, file, shell, freopen

I'm trying to make a shell in C. Everything works except file redirection. I think my code looks correct and I've tried about everything to get it working. The problem is that when the user inputs >> (ex. ls -l >> foo.txt) it's supposed to append to an existing file, but in my code it overwrites the file. My program is detecting the >> but I have no idea why it is overwriting instead of appending, because I even have "a+" in freopen. All of the arguments are being passed correctly but reopen is being difficult.

My Problematic Code:

```
if(fork()==0)
            {
                int error;
                FILE *fp;
                if(tokens[1]!=NULL)
                {

                    char *args[3] = {tokens[0], tokens[1], NULL};
                    int i=0;
                    int argument = 2;

                    for(i = 0; i < strlen(user_input_copy);i++)
                    {
                        if(user_input_copy[i] == '<')
                        {
                            printf("HERE <\n");
                            fp = freopen(tokens[argument],"r",stdin);
                        }

                        else if(user_input_copy[i] == '>' && user_input_copy[i+1] == '>')
                        {
                            printf("HERE >>\n");
                            fp = freopen(tokens[argument],"a+",stdout);
                        }

                        else if(user_input_copy[i] == '>')
                        {
                            printf("HERE >\n");
                            fp = freopen(tokens[argument],"w+",stdout); 
                        }

                    }
                    error = execvp(args[0],args);
          }
```

Comment: On first pass where `user_input_copy[i] == '>'`, it did append. But on the next pass, `user_input_copy[i] == '>'` is still true therefore the file is overwritten. You will need to move past the `user_input_copy[i+1]` when the user input has `>>`.

Comment: That was the problem, thank you!